# How to remove underline in input text while typing and change color of cursor pointer for Android device using nativescript-Angular

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm developing a native mobile app using nativescript-Angular. I would like text typed by user while filling personal details should not have underline. Also I want to change the color of cursor pointer to different color

[image]

Comment: I think you are referring to [autocorrect](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_text_field_.textfield#autocorrect), simply set the property to false on the text field.

Comment: while typing text  in text field underline coming under the text I used autocorrect="false" but it not working

Comment: Setting autocorrect to false works with Android's default keyboard. If you are using Google Keyboard then they doesn't seem to honour this property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `autocorrect` to `false` should disable suggestion bar above keyboard as well the underline on word being inputted.

But for some reason it doesn't seem to work with Google Keyboard (Gboard). A workaround could be setting the input type to visible password,

**HTML**

```
<TextField (loaded)="onTextFieldLoaded($event)"></TextField>
```

**TS**

```
 // At top of the file
 declare var android;     

 ....

 onTextFieldLoaded(event) {
    if (event.object.android) {
       event.object.android.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD | android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
    }
 }
```

Comment: above code working fine but problem with  font-family and font-weight of input text how to change font family and font weight

Comment: That's not part of this question, just refer the [styling docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling) for those.

Comment: after applying this solution font family and font size changed

Comment: I don't see any issues on my end. Please share a Playground Sample.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use this code for remove underline in textfield.

```
<StackLayout class="form input-field">
    <TextField class="input" autocorrect="false" hint="type"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
```

**2.** Change color of cursor pointer for setting your accent color in app/App_Resources/Android/values and app/App_Resources/Android/values-v21 do not forget to reset your platforms folder delete it and rebuild your application.

Comment: text input unwanted underline still displaying

Comment: remove input-border css class in text-field.

Comment: @Luke I guess he is pointing the underline that appears in the textfield while auto suggestion is enabled.